# Spying on React components using Enzyme (and sinon?) to check arguments

Tags: testing, reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I'm wanting to assert that a component gets called from within another component with the correct arguments.

So within the component that I am testing there is a `Title` component that gets called with properties `title` & `url`. I'm trying to assert that it gets called with the correct arguments.

I'm pretty sure I want to use a `sinon` spy and do something like this

```
const titleSpy = sinon.spy(Title, render)
expect(titleSpy).to.be.calledWith( '< some title >' )
```

but with regards to React and Enzyme, I'm not really sure *what* I should be spying on. (Because apparently it's not `render`!)

In my spec file I am importing `Title` and `console.log`ing it's value to find a function to spy on and I get:

```
function _class() {
  _classCallCheck(this, _class);
  return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(_class).apply(this, arguments));
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? Is it a case of going through and finding the element and checking it's attributes? If so that seems a bit...messy and seems like it goes against the principle of the Shallow render (*"Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit"*).

Comment: Did I understood correctly that you are just tried to test if certain props where passed to a component?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr yes, essentially that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with the help of  `.contains()` method, without messing up with *spies*.

If you have a component:

```
<Foo>
  <Title title="A title" url="http://google.com" />
</Foo>
```

You can make such an assertion:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
expect(wrapper.contains(<Title title="A title" url="http://google.com" />)).to.equal(true);
```

Such will fail:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
expect(wrapper.contains(<Title title="A wrong title" url="http://youtube.com" />)).to.equal(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just checking the value of properties passed to the component, you don't need sinon. For example, given the following component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <MyComponent myProp={this.props.myProp} />)
    }
}
```

Your test might look like this:

```
describe('MyComponent ->', () => {

    const props = {
        myProp: 'myProp'
    }

    it('should set myProp from props', () => {          
        const component = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />)
        expect(component.props().myProp).to.equal(props.myProp)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but my approach is a little different than the existing answers:

> So **within** the component that I am testing there is a Title component that gets called with properties title & url. I'm trying to assert that it gets called with the correct arguments.

ie. You're wanting to check that **the component being tested renders another component, and passes the correct prop(s) to it.**

So if the component being tested looks something like:

```
const MyComp = ({ title, url }) => (
  <div>
    <Title title={title} url={url} />
  </div>
)
```

Then the test could look something like:

```
import Title from 'path/to/Title';, u

it('renders Title correctly', () => {
  const testTitle = 'Test title';
  const testUrl = 'http://example.com';
  const sut = enzyme.shallow(<MyComp title={testTitle} url={testUrl} />);

  // Check tested component rendered
  expect(sut.exists).toBeTruthy(); 

  // Find the Title component in the subtree
  const titleComp = sut.find(Title); // or use a css-style selector string instead of the Title import

  // Check that we found exactly one Title component
  expect(titleComp).toHaveLength(1);

  // Check that the props that were passed were our test values
  expect(titleComp.prop('title')).toBe(testTitle);
  expect(titleComp.prop('url')).toBe(testUrl);
});
```

I generally find Enzyme's functions to be very useful for all kinds of checks about components, without needing other libraries. Creating Sinon mocks can be useful to pass as props to components, to (for example) test that a callback prop is called when a button is clicked.